# Getting error when free() a chunk of memory

Tags: c

The below program takes input `a sentence`, `an old word`, and a `new word`.
The objective is to `replace all the occurrences old word with the new word`.

```
int countOccurrence(char* sen,char* word) //counts occurrences of old word
{
    int count=0,i,k,len1,len2;

    len1=strlen(sen);
    len2=strlen(word);
    for(i=0;i<len1-len2+1;)
    {
            k=0;
            while(word[k] && sen[k+i]==word[k])
                    k++;
            if(k==len2 && sen[k+i]==' ' || sen[k+i]=='\0')
            {
                    count++;
                    i+=len2;
            }
            else ++i;
    }
    return count;
}

void replace(char* sen,char* oldword,char* newword)
{
    int count,len1,len2,len3,i,top=-1,k;
    char *ptr;

    count=countOccurrence(sen,oldword);

    if(!count) return;

    len1=strlen(sen);
    len2=strlen(oldword);
    len3=strlen(newword);

    ptr=(char*)malloc(sizeof(len1+count*(len3-len2)+1));

    for(i=0;i<len1-len2+1;)
    {
            k=0;
            while(oldword[k] && sen[k+i]==oldword[k])
                    k++;
            if(k==len2 && sen[k+i]==' ' || sen[k+i]=='\0')
            {
                    for(k=0;newword[k];++k)
                            ptr[++top]=newword[k];
                    i+=len2;
            }
            else
            {
                    ptr[++top]=sen[i];
                    ++i;
            }
    }       
    ptr[++top]='\0';

    strcpy(sen,ptr);

    free(ptr); <-------------------------------
}
```

After executing, i am getting the error as: http://ideone.com/mh3X1

```
*** glibc detected *** ./prog: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x08f49008 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0xb75fcfd4]
/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x9c)[0xb75fe87c]
./prog[0x8048834]
./prog[0x80484c1]
======= Memory map: ========
```

The programs works when i comment the statement:

```
free(ptr);
```

see here: http://ideone.com/fr34H

**Why i am getting error when i try to free() the memory allocated on heap?**

Comment: is "sen" big enough to receive the final strcpy() result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You messed up the internal information kept by `malloc` and it detected it when at the next operations (which was the free). Here's the reason:

```
ptr=(char*)malloc(sizeof(len1+count*(len3-len2)+1));
                  ^^^^^^
```

In this context the sizeof evaluates to the size of the integer on your platform: almost surely **less than what you want**. So when you write to `ptr`, after 4 or 8 bytes you'll step outside the allocated area and all bets are off.

---

Side note: it's largely a matter of taste but you should probably stop casting the value returned by `malloc`.

Answer (score 4):

This line is suspect:

```
ptr=(char*)malloc(sizeof(len1+count*(len3-len2)+1));
```

You don't want `sizeof` there.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical case of heap corruption. Somewhere in your program, you are writing out of the boundaries of some dynamic array, overwriting data necessary for `free` to understand what it should do.

Try running [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/):

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./your_program
```

As others have mentioned, you haven't properly allocated memory for `ptr`. Another problem I can see is `strcpy(sen,ptr);`. The size of the end result may be bigger than the sentence, therefore you go over the boundaries of `sen` also.